# cp - cannot create regular file : permission denied

Tags: permissions, root, cp

I want copy to `/lib/udev` but gives error

```
cp -f /tmp/ok_pcscd_hotplug.sh /lib/udev

cp:cannot create regular file /lib/udev/ok_pcscd_hotplug : Permission denied
```

I am root , but I can't understand . what can I do ?

Comment: In my case, when I needed to copy something onto exFAT, it failed at each file which had a "|" in it's filename.

Answer (score 40):

Check if you are really superuser with:

```
whoami
```

if the output is `root`, then you are superuser and you can make the copy of the file with:

```
cp -f /tmp/ok_pcscd_hotplug.sh /lib/udev/.
```

otherwise you have to use `sudo`:

```
sudo cp -f /tmp/ok_pcscd_hotplug.sh /lib/udev/.
```

If you're still not able to write to the directory, then it is possible that:

1. the directory has the immutable flag enabled. check with `lsattr`.
2. the directory is mounted with read-only permissions: type in terminal:

   `cat /proc/mounts` (or `mount` or `cat /etc/mtab`)

   and check the output, if directory is mounted read-only.

If you are in the first case, change the directory attributes with `chattr`;

- remove immutable flag on file or directory `chattr -i <file/dir>`
- adding immutable flag on file or directory again `chattr +i <file/dir>`

If you're in the latter case, edit the file `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: whoami - output root

i tried cp -f and sudo cp -f , but gives error again

Comment: I made ​​a small change to my answer: I copied the command from your question, but there is an error: the command as you wrote, it will overwrite udev, you must add `/.` at the end of the command to copy the files in the directory

Comment: i tried :

cp -f /tmp/ok_pcscd_hotplug.sh /lib/udev/.
cp -f /tmp/ok_pcscd_hotplug.sh /lib/udev/
cp /tmp/ok_pcscd_hotplug.sh /lib/udev

i don't understand , i'm root but don't copied 
where is the problem

Comment: I edited my answer, post in your question also output of `mount` and `lsattr /lib/`

Comment: mount /lib/ - mount:can't find /lib/ in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
lsattr /lib/ - Inapppropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on lib/filename output for everyfile

Comment: Use command `mount`, without `/lib/`, but please edit your question, not copy output in comment.

Comment: i use chattr and output 

chattr:Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on /lib/udev ?
and 
where is edit in /etc/fstab ?
thanks

Comment: I am confused. I am trying to copy a file from a cdrom to my home dir. Why would I not always have permission to write to my home directory?

Comment: I had accidentally added a trailing } to the script generated file name  . My problem was not noticing the } in the error message

Answer (score 4):

Its not necessary every time that you need to be root for this purpose
So if you want to do it with root user its fine, but if you want to do it without root, then you have 2 options:

1. Check the permissions of file. You must have read permissions to that
2. Check that file or link with same name is not present in the destination directory.       Because if link with same name is there in destination directory, it won't allow you to do that and also will not warn that link with same name is present

Answer (score 3):

You should create directory first if `/lib/udev` doesn't exist

```
mkdir -p /lib/udev
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `cp /tmp/ok_pcscd_hotplug.sh /lib/udev/` in root user.

Comment: dont change,gives error again - 

root@atrust-00351A:/lib# ls-l
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 324 2009-05-22 11:40 udev

Comment: Please post the output `whoami` and `ls -al /tmp/ok_pcscd_hotplug.sh`

Comment: whoami - output root
ls -al /tmp/ok_pcscd_hotplug.sh - output
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 229

Comment: Then make sure that `ok_pcscd_hotplug.sh` is not corrupted and `/lib/udev/` exist in your system.

Comment: either ok_pcscd_hot_plug.sh or /lib/udev avaliable on system

Answer (score 0):

First do " ls -l  " and check the permissions for this directory. If you see something like -rw-r--r-- , that means  Owner can read-write, Usergroup can only read, World can only read. Type in the following command if this be the case : " chmod 766  ". This will allow you to perform read-write operations on that file. Now try copying that file  the same way. It should work

Comment: * chmod 766 <file/dir>

Comment: You can still edit the answer and add that. And I don't believe in granting all permissions to users. Instead if folder/file is to be made login as the user who has privileges. Thanks. :-)